# Interesting git rebase scenario with two branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

I was working with two git branches.

```
a -- b -- c                  <-- master
           \
            d                <-- newbranch
```

After reaching `commit d`, I realized I need to change `commit c` a little bit. I went into master branch and amended `commit c`. Now, `commit c` became `commit e`. `c and e` has the same commit message.

```
a -- b -- e                  <-- master
      \     
       c -- d                <-- newbranch
```

So, now my `commit c` is useless. Now `commit c` and `commit e` are conflicting in few files and in all the files they are conflicting I will prefer the changes of `commit e` to stay. Also, `commit d` has important changes that I don't wanna lose.

I want my final structure to be something like this.

```
a -- b -- e -- f             <-- master
```

where `commit f` is the amended version of `commit d`, having the same commit message.

I tried rebasing the master into newbranch first and was thinking of rebasing the newbranch into master later on. But as there lots of conflicts and after manually solving the conflicts I lost my way and became clueless and then lost all the manual correction and need to start rebase again.

If someone please guide me about the exact procedure to follow in my approach or have a better solution please share. Thank you.

Comment: Go on newbranch, use `git rebase -i master`, and skip commit c. See here for informations about interactive rebase : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode

Comment: @Hugal31 The `c` commit is no longer part of the history of `master`, AFAIK.

Comment: Yes. A regular rebase would end up with `master: a -- b -- e -- c --d`, but if you **skip** the commit *c*, you get `a -- b -- e -- d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is probably to just cherry pick the `d` commit from `newbranch` onto `master`:

```
# from master
git cherry-pick d
```

This would leave us with the following branch structure:

```
master: a -- b -- e -- f  (*f is actually the cherry pick of d)
              \     
                c -- d
```

Comment: For more than one commit, however, rebase onto is a good step.